# Flutter API Get request hanging

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, dart

I'm a beginner with Flutter and am trying to print a list of doctors in a widget via a GET request and FutureBuilder. All doctors are currently in a local MySQL database and are accessible via [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIMLZ.png), but the GET request seems to hang in my code.

I've tried using the code snippet provided by [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dy3O.png) and the same issue seems to occur. Here is my code:

```
class _DoctorSelectionScreen extends State<DoctorSelectionScreen> {
  DoctorService doctorService = DoctorService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: const NavigationDrawerWidget(),
        appBar:
            AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.green, title: const Text("Doctors")),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: doctorService.getDoctors(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Doctor>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Doctor>? doctors = snapshot.data;
                // return Column(children: <Widget>[
                //   for (var doctor in doctors!) buildDoctor(doctor)
                // ]);
                return const Center(child: Text("Found doctors"));
              } else {
                return const Center(child: Text("No doctors found."));
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class DoctorService {
  final String appointmentURL = 'localhost:8082/appointments';

  Future<List<Doctor>> getDoctors() async {
    print("TEST");
    var res = await get(Uri.parse(appointmentURL));
    print("TEST2");

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final obj = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<Doctor> doctors = <Doctor>[];
      return doctors;
    } else {
      throw "Unable to retrieve doctors.";
    }
  }
}
```

The code seems to hang at:

```
var res = await get(Uri.parse(appointmentURL));
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should debug your getDoctors method. Does it go into the if? What status do you get back? Does it crash? Any output in the console? :D

Comment: I have two print statements in getDoctors, one before await get and one after. Print statement before executes and prints fine but second one doesn't print to console.

Comment: Could you provide the status code you are getting ?

Comment: In Postman next to status it says 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying this on an emulator then the localhost for the emulator is not `127.0.0.0` it is `10.0.2.2`, so you need to write `https://10.0.2.2:YOUR_PORT_NO`. Also `https://127.0.0.0:YOUR_PORT_NO` won't work on a real device as well.

You can check [this](https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130) for more detailed information.